# Check if any column is NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to check whether a column is NOT NULL in my SQL statement.

My SQL query:

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_x
from myTable
```

I've a lot of columns in my select. So I've got a performance issue, If I would do the following:

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_x
from myTable
where column_a is not null or column_b is not null or column_c is not null 
or column_x  is not null
```

Is there another (better) way to check if there are any columns that are NOT NULL?

Comment: Why do you say that is a performance issue? Are most of these column values actually `NULL` so it is scanning unnecessary rows? How have you come to this conclusion?

Comment: You could put the columns containing the least amount of NULL first? How about an index on all columns?

Comment: Do you want to know if any column has a NULL value (as stated in the question title and question body), or whether any column does **not** have a NULL value (as written in your SQL query). Two completely different questions.

Comment: First - amazing how much answers and comments in such a small time! Thanks a lot!
@Martin Smith: In my table, I've a performance issue (> 20k records), If I do the select * from myTable where colum_a is not null or column_b is not null and so far.

Comment: @RedFilter: I want to know whether one column have a "not-null" value. If a column have a "not-null" value the row will display and won't be filtered. Sorry for my imprecise question.

Comment: @pro: I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: That is the correct syntax and 20K records is small.  Define poor perfomance - milliseconds, seconds, minutes?  Are those columns indexed?

Comment: The non-functional requirement for my script is under 2s for >20k records.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` for this. `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value, if any. This will likely not perform any better, but is much more readable.

**Example:**

```
where coalesce(column_a, column_b, column_c, column_x) is not null
```

Depending on the cardinality of your data, you may be able to add indexes to help performance.

Another possibility is to use persisted computed column that tells you whether all four columns are NULL or not.

Comment: You *could* but you wouldn't know which column is null (except that a null result means they all are). If OP wants to confirm every column is null, then a COALESCE would work well. However, it wouldn't be a concise way to detect if *any* column is null .

Comment: @Brad: the OP is selecting where any column is **not** null. `COALESCE` works perfectly for this and provides no more or less info than the original query does.

Comment: I'm understanding the question as "how do I detect if any of these columns are null". A COALESCE isn't going to tell you if a single column is null, just that at least one isn't or all of them are. So as long as the first column isn't null, you're really ignoring a test on the next three. (Likewise for the first two compared against last two, and so on). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Brad: I see where your confusion is now. The question title conflicts with the question body, and the question body text conflicts with the SQL query. I am going with the logic provided in the OP's SQL query.

Comment: I would say your footnote is a better method than using a COALESCE. Use an integer column tallying nulls/non-nulls making a query much less intensive (however now you're dependent on triggers; pick your poison I guess).

Comment: @BradChristie - It will make little difference (except in terms of sargibility) as these columns need to be brought back for the select list anyway.

Comment: @Brad: I am suggesting [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) - triggers are not needed in this case.

Comment: @RedFilter: Thanks for this answer. But I think, that I've got a performance issue with coalesce, or what do you think? I will test it :-)

Comment: @RedFilter: Computed columns sound nice!

Comment: @RedFilter I receive a 'Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime' error when trying to coalesce columns of multiple types in this way (including datetime and guid).

Answer (score 3):

One way to attack this might be to add an additional bit column that keeps track of whether there are any values or not.

**Pros**

- Can be implemented with triggers so you don't need to change the rest of your code
- Doesn't require scanning the other columns
- That column can be indexed

**Cons**

- Your data would be de-normalized
- More complicated / more maintenance
- More storage space for the additional column

Whether the pros outweigh the cons depend on how much of a performance hit you're taking by looking at the other columns.  Profile it before committing!

Comment: The index would probably not be used unless it covered `column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_x` anyway because of the cost of lookups unless they were in an unusual situation where this was `NULL` for all columns for the vast majority of rows so might as well use a filtered index or indexed view with the `NOT NULL` criteria directly.

Comment: Hi RQDQ, Thanks for your answer. I assume,that it's a big overhead,  If i do a seperate column for this value. Perhaps in the sql query with a temperary table?

Answer (score 2):

I generally like @RedFilter's suggestion of COALESCE, but another solution might be to use the CHECKSUM() function.  Of course, the value of the checksum for all NULLs depends on the columns and datatypes so you would need to first run a query to get that value.  Something like:

```
select CHECKSUM(*) AS [All_NULL_Value]
from myTable
where column_a is null
AND column_b is null
AND column_c is null
AND column_d is null
AND column_x  is null
```

Then you can do this:

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d, column_x
from myTable
where CHECKSUM(*) <> {All_NULL_Value_obtained_above}
```

I am not sure if this performs better or worse than the COALESCE idea but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Answer accepted 5 years ago, but, as said Brad, by question title coalesce is wrong approach. If in some cases you really need to check or ANY parameter is null, you can use this:

```
where convert(binary, column_a) + convert(binary, column_b) + convert(binary, column_c), + convert(binary, column_k) is null
```